# Importing ArrayList without IDE package

Tags: java

How can I count my messages? I have both classes in the same folder and I compile them in the terminal. I don't want to install an IDE and create a package.

My counting class:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class countMessages{
  public static void main(String args[]){

    int count = messages.size();

  }
}
```

My message containing class:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class SampleDataBase {

public static ArrayList<String> messages;

  static {
    messages = new ArrayList<String>(12);
    messages.add("A "+"message "+"with "+"pineapples.");
    messages.add("A "+"message "+"with "+"grapes.");
    messages.add("A "+"message "+"with "+"watermelons.");
  }

}
```

Comment: `int count = SampleDataBase.messages.size();`?

Comment: btw, a "package" is just a folder/directory. You don't need an IDE to create one. And you want your files in one folder anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a package just create a folder (name it for example myPackage) and put both classes in it. Also include a first line in both class files: `package myPackage;`. Remember to name the class files with the names of the classes.

To make your example work just change `messages.size();` to `SampleDataBase.messages.size();`.

And you really should name the class CountMessages with a capital letter.

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear what you are trying to do but what I think you are looking for is  a main static method(?)

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class SampleDataBase
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        ArrayList<String> messages = new ArrayList<>();
        messages.Add("things...");

        for(String message : messages)
        {
            System.out.println(message);
        }

        System.out.println("The number of messages is : " + messages.size());
    }
}
```

in the terminal, to use:

Compile `javac *.java`
Execute `java SampleDataBase`

Answer (score -1):

If you want to keep two classes, use this on your test class(that contains main method).

```
public class countMessages{
  public static void main(String args[]){
// You must instantiate the other class
    SampleDataBase sdb = new SampleDataBase();

 // here you will get the total messages in your arrayList
int count = sdb.messages.size();

 }
```

Comment: -1 - `SimpleDataBase.messages` is `static`, so it is NOT necessary to instantiate the other class to access `messages`

Comment: Hum... Try to call the method     messages from     SimpleDataBase class without instantiate it, and then vote my answer again. It must to declare explicit the name of class, like     SimpleDataBase.messages.size(); It works like an instance from the class, but as I said, an explicit declartion of the class.

Comment: If you don't believe me, try Quizzie's solution.  Then explain how >>HE<< manages to get his code to work without instantiating the class.

Comment: Oh man, don't be annoying. I said two answers. First, you must instantiate the class and then use the method, like my accepted answer; Second, explicitly declare the class name, like     SampleDataBase.messages.size(); In anyway, you MUST declare from WHERE it comes!